# How to notify AngularJS that a form has been filled externally by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a page in AngularJS which has a form containing some fields. Upon loading that page, I want a bookmark which when clicked to fill the fields based on data in a configuration file. A JS file is being used which uses jquery to fill the data in the form

When I do `$("#id").val('abcd')`, the field gets populated with text `abcd`, but angularjs thinks the form is still invalid.The classes `ng-pristine ng-invalid` still remain on the element. I tried removing the using jquery's `removeClass()` and adding the `ng-dirty ng-valid` classes using `addClass()` but still the state of the form remains as invalid.

How do I let angularjs know that the form fields have been populated and the form is valid?

Comment: if you are using angularjs, you should not need to set values with `$("#id").val('abcd')` but you should use `ng-model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-model` controller listens to the `'change'` event.

```
<input id="id" ng-model="$ctrl.text" />
```

To trigger it from jQuery:

```
$("#id").val("abcd").trigger("change");
```

This will set the value of the input and trigger the `ngModelController` to update the model in the AngularJS framework.

### The DEMO

```js
$(function() {
  $("#bt").on("click", function() {
    $("#id").val("abcd").trigger("change");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input id="id" ng-model="$ctrl.text" /><br>
    text={{$ctrl.text}}<br>
    <button id="bt">Click me</button>
</body>
```

---

## Note

It is important to load the jQuery library *before* the AngularJS library.

From the Docs:

> To use `jQuery`, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file.

For more information, see [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Answer (score -1):

Call $apply after the data has been entered.

`$scope.$apply()`

This is used to hook into angular's digest cycle when events occur outside of angular.

From the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the AngularJS framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

Comment: I am trying it on the console. But after setting my value and entering this code, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`. Please help!

Comment: You'll need to post some code for me to help you.  I can't debug your problem without seeing what you are working with.

Comment: You might not have injected `$scope` into the controller? or service? you are attempting to call `$apply`